# JavaScript regex syntax highlighting issue

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

```js
if(!/^https?:\/\//.test(val) && foo == 'bar') {
    val = 'http://' + val;
}
```

As you can see, the `//` causes the highlighter to switch to comment mode which is incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an issue with Google Prettify, I think.

[I've submitted a bug report.](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=217)

Update: [resolved](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=217)